# Make distributed points on faces' rotation follow a curve orientation - Blender GeoNode

Tags: node-editor, geometry, instances

I have troubles making distributed instances rotation follow curve orientation.

This is what I got: (red arrow is showing the unwanted orientation)

[image]

This is what I want (red arrow is showing the wanted orientation):

[image]

This is my geometry:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to align objects along a mesh that you have previously created with `Curve to Mesh`, you would need two parameters:

- The tangents of the curve points (or the course of the curve).
- The normals of the curve points

In your case, you would have to capture these before converting the curves into a mesh.

Then you can use these two parameters in combination with the node `Align Euler to Vector` to create a rotation that aligns the axes of the instantiated objects to the curve:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I need

Comment: @Sicarius1 You are welcome!